# Not able to simulate key events in Message app using Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent

Tags: tizen

I have created sample application that will launch Message app, which in turn generates and sends `KEY_1` using `Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent().`

Here is code snippet:

```
String strAppName = L"tizen.messages";
result r;

Tizen::App::AppControl* pAc = AppManager::FindAppControlN(strAppName, L"http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/compose");
if (pAc)
{
    r = pAc->Start(null, null, null, null);
    delete pAc;
}
AppLog("Application launch status : [%s]", GetErrorMessage(r));

sleep(2);

Tizen::Ui::KeyCode keyToSimulate = Tizen::Ui::KEY_1;

r = Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent(Tizen::Ui::KEY_EVENT_TYPE_PRESSED, keyToSimulate);
AppLog("KEY_EVENT_TYPE_PRESSED [%d] and result :: %s", keyToSimulate, GetErrorMessage(r));
r = Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent(Tizen::Ui::KEY_EVENT_TYPE_RELEASED, keyToSimulate);
AppLog("KEY_EVENT_TYPE_RELEASED [%d] and result :: %s", keyToSimulate, GetErrorMessage(r));
```

Application launched successfully and the result of the GenerateKeyEvent pressed and released is `E_SUCCESS`. The value **'1'** is not getting printed on the Message app.

Please help me to simulate the keys.

Thanks,

Anil.

Comment: I can able to simulate the events successfully on giving some characters manually.

Answer (score 0):

May be its not the way to do it, you should pass the data to the message app within the parameters of `pAc->Start`. Thats how normally `tizen` app works, You are not defining where to simulate the keyEvent isn't it.`You dont have control over other App to simulate an event on it`. You can define the data to pass within a `IList` or `HashMap` in the parameters, Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Arju for your reply. I am not looking to send the values in advance through the App Control while launching the app. I need to simulate the key events in Message App. With out entering manually i am looking to automate through GenerateKeyEvent() API.

Comment: I think that will not be possible in any app, because if you develop an app do you allow other app to automate it?

Comment: Yes Arju, Its possible i can able to simulate Touch events followed by key Events.